# Run last command with all the letters transformed to lowercase

Tags: command-line, bash, history

Many times I have run a command with all the letters in uppercase (maybe because <kbd>CapsLock</kbd> was on), and I pressed <kbd>Enter</kbd> before realising this.

How can I run the last command with all the letters transformed to lowercase?

Comment: Shame you're not using zsh. `!!:l`.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can accomplish that by adding the following small function (I call it `??` to be very simple, but you can change this as you wish) in your `.bashrc` file:

```
?? () { "${@,,}"; }
```

Next, when you will run:

```
?? !!
```

the last command will be run with all the letters to lowercase.

#### Explanation

- `!!` :  this is part of bash's history tools, specifically, [it expands to the last command run](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Event-Designators). So, for example, `echo !!` will print out the last command run in this particular shell session.
- `"${@,,}` : The construct `${foo,,}` [will convert the contents](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) of the variable `$foo` converted to all lowercase letters. `$@` is the array of positional parameters.  When used inside a function, it is expanded to the parameters passed to that function.

So, `"${@,,}"` will simply convert whatever was passed to the function into lowercase and then execute it. Therefore, running the `??` function with `!!` as a parameter will convert the last command to lowercase and run it.

Comment: Perhaps you could add an explanation of how this works? It is very cryptic the way you've written it. Also, it doesn't actually work, as such. As you've written it, it will only work correctly if your PWD is empty. You need to quote the `"!!"`.

Comment: @terdon Now, thanks to glenn, it should work in any case... And there is nothing too much to explain: the function `??` converts its arguments letters to lowercaes and `!!` re-write automaticaly the previous command in the current command (so `??` takes as argument the previous command).

Answer (score 6):

```
`echo  !! | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]'`
```

The key is in the `` ` `` (backticks) quotations - which runs the output as a command.

Comment: The backticks where invisible in the first version of the answer, due to the markup language. No need to downvote (without comment) for this; just edit.

Comment: `tr` would be my first choice, too.   Also works (alternative to backticks and without the POSIX bracket-classes) : `$( echo !! | tr '[A-Z]' '[a-z]')`

Answer (score 4):

here comes a programmers answer.... use python:

```
`echo "print '!!'.lower()" | python`
```

Or Ruby:

```
`echo "print '!!'.downcase" | ruby`
```

Or Perl (probably my favorite):

```
`perl -e "print lc('!!');"`
```

Or PHP:

```
`php -r "print strtolower('!!');"`
```

Or Awk:

```
`echo "!!" | awk '{ print tolower($1) }'`
```

Or Sed:

```
`echo "!!" | sed 's/./\L&/g'`
```

Or Bash:

```
str="!!" ; ${str,,}
```

Or zsh

```
echo "A='!!' ; \$A:l" | zsh
```

Or NodeJS if you have it:

```
`echo "console.log('!!'.toLowerCase());" | node`
```

You could also use `dd` (but I wouldn't!):

```
 `echo "!!" | dd  conv=lcase 2> /dev/null`
```

You could also create a small script to do the job:

```
sudo bash -c 'cat << EOF > /usr/local/bin/lower
#!/usr/bin/python
import fileinput
print "".join(fileinput.input()).lower(),
EOF' && sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/lower
```

Which you use like so:

```
`echo !! | lower`
```

Answer (score 1):

And the one with `sed`,

```
$(echo !! | sed 's/^\(.*\)$/\L\1/g')
```

Example:

```
$ SUDO APT-GET UPDATE
SUDO: command not found
$ $(echo !! | sed 's/^\(.*\)$/\L\1/g')
```

Output:

```
$(echo SUDO APT-GET UPDATE | sed 's/^\(.*\)$/\L\1/g')
[sudo] password for avinash: 
0% [Waiting for headers] [Waiting for headers] [Waiting for headers] [Connectin^
```